# upgrade ionic 3 to ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic5

The old project that I'm trying to upgrade has a custom CSS for the native element

```
      .searchbar-input {
        padding: 6px 55px;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-position: left 8px center;
        height: auto;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        font-weight: 400;
        line-height: 3rem;
        color: #141414;
        background-color: #fff;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    }
```

although we can't do something similar with ionic 4/5 because most of the CSS encapsulated inside of the component. is there a possibility to make me edit the native element CSS or importing my old style to the new project?

Comment: Looking at customization here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar#css-custom-properties - what specifically is an issue? font-size? what CSS rule is not available in practice to you? can you share working code example?

Comment: the main issue here is that I cant add style to the native element any more as I used to in the previous Version (3)  the class .searchbar-input is wrapped in the ion-searchbar I'm only giving this example because is the easiest to understand the problem

Comment: Try adding the CSS to your global.scss file. Ionic 4 & 5 have introduced shadow-DOM and most of the properties are not directly accessible.

Comment: Of course, I tried that I have success with the width attribute ... but still, I don't have the accessibility over the native elements